# Crash report reading

Tags: ios, xcode, cydia

1st question :

Can anyone please help me find the error which causing my app to crash through this crashing report : [crash report](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=fystj&s=8) thanks for all in instance.

the app crashes once it is launched.

the app is for jailbroken iphones.

2nd question :

when i update the app in my repo everything goes well and an update shows in cydia normally. but some users are complaining that the app is crashing after updating also. where the packaging i am doing is the same as described on saurik website. what can cause such issue ??

Update, crash report from user:

Last Exception Backtrace:

0 CoreFoundation 0x18438659c 0x184260000 + 0x12659c // __exceptionPreprocess + 0x84
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x194adc0e4 0x194ad4000 + 0x80e4 // objc_exception_throw + 0x3c
2 CoreFoundation 0x1843864dc 0x184260000 + 0x1264dc // -[NSException  initWithCoder:] + 0x0
3 App () 0x1000d4fdc 0x100064000 + 0x70fdc // PFQueryAssertValidEqualityClauseClass + 0x158
4 App () 0x1000d4e20 0x100064000 + 0x70e20 // -[PFQuery whereKey:equalTo:] + 0x50
5 App (*) 0x10007aa60 0x100064000 + 0x16a60 // -[ViewController ackPicture:] + 0x104

Comment: this crash log was sent from user if it may help

Comment: Looks like the crash was in `PFQuery`. (Added backtrack comment to the question for formatting)

Answer (score 0):

To see the actual statement that is causing the error add an exception breakpoint:

1. From the Main Menu Debug:Breakpoints:Create Exception Breakpoint.
2. Right-click the breakpoint and set the exception to Objective-C.
3. Add an action: "po $arg1".

Run the app to get the breakpoint and you will be at the line that causes the exception and the error message will be in the debugger console.

Breakpoint example:
[image]

Comment: the problem is in xcode and on my iphone i am not getting this error .. only some users are complaining about it so i added crash reporter in app and found the error displayed in the screenshot above.